# Apparently contradictory output from Series and D

Tags: bugs, series-expansion, differentials

I defined a function as:

```
g[b_] := Integrate[f[n]Exp[-b  DA (n.u)^2], n]
```

Obviously

```
 D[g[b], b] /. b -> 0
```

gives

> ```
> (-DA)*Integrate[(n.u)^2*f[n], n]
> ```

But, then, how can

```
Series[g[b], {b, 0, 2}]
```

be

> ```
> Integrate[f[n], n]
> ```

I guess there is something basic I don't understand. Something with order of evaluation? It's like `b = 0` is evaluated before the differentiation in `Series`.

Comment: Please give reason for negative votes so I can learn!

Comment: I guess formatting (please read [these guidelines](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)). Also,your code is not self-contained. There are undefined symbols, like f, u and DA.

Comment: What do you think that `n.u` means? You use n as the integration variable, so it is one-dimensional. N.u is a vector operation.

Comment: a dot product of n and u

Comment: And thanks for feedback about the post formatting etc. f u and Da are supposed to not be defined, because they are undefined to Mathematica.

Comment: Yes, but it applies to scalars as well, it is just a special case of a vector to Mathematica, right? (I do that way for other reasons.) However, it is irrelevant to the problem, same thing happens when I write n u instead.

Comment: No, it doesn't apply to scalars. Try `u = 1; n = 1; u.n`

Comment: Ok you're right about that.

Comment: Note: `Integrate[Series[f[n] Exp[-b DA (n u)^2], {b, 0, 2}], n]` returns `Integrate[f[n], n]`.  But `Integrate[Normal@Series[..], n]` works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Not answer, but an observation of where the problem is (too small to fit in comment).

If you simplify the function to

```
  g[b_] := Integrate[ f[n] Exp[-b n ], n];
```

Now, applying `Series[g[x],{x,0,1}]`, and applying the `Series` manually (from definition) to see the difference:

```
  (g[b] /. b -> 0) + (D[g[b], b] /. b -> 0) x
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now using the Series command:

```
  Series[g[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Ok, so where is the problem? `Series` is not integrating it correctly when there is a `b` inside `Exp[]` (`b` is the input symbol to the function). This works:

```
   g[b_] := Integrate[ f[n] Exp[-n], n];
```

But once `b` is added inside the integrand and has to be inside `Exp[]`, it fails. Need more Tracing to find where exactly it failed.

Note: I think this is a bug. I verified with Maple, and it gives the results, which matches the manual method:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Agree so far :-)

Comment: I also feel this is a bug. Note, BTW, that the `O[x]^3` is suspiciously missing.

Comment: The missing O[x]^3 is also consistent with x=0 being (inapproriately) evaluated before the differentiation...

Comment: @sune I don't think so. It's even there (unnecessary) in `Series[x, {x, 0, 2}]`.

Comment: But when it's a constant, such as after x=0, it's different, and there is no O[x]^3. Try e.g. `Series[1, {x, 0, 2}]`. Also, if you do `Series[Log[g[x]], {x, 0, 2}]` you do get the O[x]^3, but it's still wrong. Looks like I should submit a bug report then.

Comment: Workaround: `Block[{g}, Series[g[b], {b, 0, 2}]]`.

Comment: Wolfram has now confirmed misbehaviour of `Series` for this case.