# How to implement a formal expectation operator over an unknown distribution?

Tags: function-construction, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

I need to do some simplification of an expression involving averages over a stochastic variable (in order to verify a  long analytical calculation).
The easiest way to do that, I figured, were if I could implement an operator which would basically be short-hand for the averaging procedure, with all the appropriate properties. Then of course this operator would be present in the final expression, which is fine, and would enable me to compare easily with my own calculations.
So assuming I use `x` for the stochastic variable, I tried defining `av` using

```
av[y_ + z_] := av[y] + av[z]  
av[c_ y_] := c av[y] /; FreeQ[c, x]   
av[c_] := c /; FreeQ[c, x]
```

Then when I write

```
D[av[x y], y]
```

I get

```
 av[x]
```

which is fine, but when I write

```
D[av[Exp[-x y]], y]
```

I get

```
-E^(-x y) y
```

instead of `-y av[Exp[-x y]]` as I want, i.e., the `av` is removed somehow.

I tried using `UpValue` for teaching *Mathematica* that it could interchange differentiation and `av`, but apparently that is not the problem.
I might be going about this entirely the wrong way, but I'd be grateful for any input. Note the builtin `Expectation` function does not accomplish it either - e.g., it doesn't handle the derivatives as a proper average operator would. For example

```
h[y_] := Expectation[y, x \[Distributed] pp] (*pp unknown density*)
```

Then

```
D[h[Exp[-x y]], x]
```

gives

```
(Expectation^(0,1))[E^(-x y),x\[Distributed]pp] (Distributed^(1,0))[x,pp]-E^(-x y) y   
(Expectation^(1,0))[E^(-x y),x\[Distributed]pp]
```

whereas I wanted

```
-y h[Exp[-y x]]
```

(i.e moving the derivative inside the averaging h).
Sune

Comment: Have you looked at `Expectation`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work the way I want.

Comment: Then why don't you include that in the question (i.e. how `Expectation` doesn't satisfy your needs)? It's much easier that way than having to guess...

Comment: Good idea. (I only found out afterwards).

Comment: Perhaps it would work if I knew how to specify that a user defined operator commutes with the `D` operator? (But that still doesn't explain why, in the two examples above using `D` on `av`,`av` is maintained in the first but not in the last.)

Answer (score 3):

I think I got it.

```
av /: D[av[f___], x_] := av[D[f, x]]
av[y_ + z_] := av[y] + av[z]
av[c_ y_] := c av[y] /; FreeQ[c, x]
av[c_] := c /; FreeQ[c, x]
D[av[x y], x]

(* y *)

D[av[Exp[-x y]], x]
(* -y av[E^(-x y)] *)
```

I  wasn't using `UpValues` correctly before.

EDIT: Well, turns out there's still a problem:

```
D[Log[av[Exp[-b x]]], b]
(* -((E^(-b x) x)/av[E^(-b x)]) *)
```

instead of

```
-(av[(E^(-b x) x)]/av[E^(-b x)])
```

What's going on?
Sune

Answer (score 0):

Just define exactly what you want:

```
av[expr_] := Integrate[f[x] expr, {x, -∞, ∞}];
```

Here `f[x]` is undefined function.

```
D[av[Exp[-x y]], y]
```

[image]

```
D[Log[av[Exp[-b x]]], b]
```

[image]

P.S. There is a possible bug

```
f[c_] := c /; FreeQ[c, x]

f'
(* 1 & *)
```

The condition was lost.

Comment: I did that for a specific case, but I have reasons for wanting something a bit more general. For example, I'm already generating a lot of output, which I intend to compare with my analytical computations, and having a compact output directly containing `av` would make it so much simpler to compare and less prone to mistakes. Also, it would make it easier to have Mathematica use the other rules that I supplied in its simplification process. And finally, it is sometimes a more complicated multidimensional interval over a complex region.

Comment: (Besides, in addition to the bug you described, there is also a bug when applying `Series` to an expression like yours, see [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35288/apparently-contradictory-output-from-series-and-d) )

Comment: @Sune I tried to implement `av`, but the main problem for me were derivatives. `D[av[f[x,y]],x]` produces a function of `x` outside `av`.

Comment: That happened to me originally, but the order of the rules is crucial. If you restart the kernel and paste it exactly as I wrote it down above, do you still have that problem?

Comment: It works not always, e.g. `y Sin[x y]`. Also, in your post you write `D[...,x]`. Did you mean `D[...,y]`? There is no derivative of `x` after averaging. In the previous comment I have the same typo.

Comment: Yes I agree, and that was a typo. (Although I'm not sure it matters to Mathematica at this stage)
maybe you are having the same problem as me, as explained in the edit to my own answer. I think it has to do with how Mathematica implements the chain rule?

Comment: For example, I have the problem with `D[Log[av[Exp[-b x]]], b]`, but not with `D[Log[av[-b x]], b] `